# Nice way to generate grid of points for use in 3d plots

Tags: r, lattice

Every so often I want to use R to plot a 3d graph, e.g. as below.

```
X=seq(-3,3,0.05)
y=c(); for(i in X) { y=c(y,rep(i,length(X))) }
x=rep(X,length(X))
z=pmin(x,y)
library(lattice)
wireframe(z~x*y, shade=TRUE, scales=list(arrows=FALSE))
```

This generates the plot just fine

[image]

but is there a more natural / efficient way of generating the `x` and `y` vectors? I want something like a "product" operator which gives me all possible pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy way to to this using `expand.grid` and `outer`:

```
library(lattice)

x <- seq(-3,3,by=0.05)
y <- seq(-3,3,by=0.05)

grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)

dim(grid)
[1] 14641     2

grid$z = with(grid, pmin(x,y))

wireframe(z ~ x*y, data=grid, shade=TRUE, main="X=Y",
scales=list(arrows=FALSE))

contourplot(z ~ x*y, data=grid, cuts=10, aspect = "iso")
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Is it worth changing the calculation of `z` and the `wireframe` so that it is consistent with the simplified question here? I.e., `z <- outer(x,y,function(x,y) {pmin(x,y)} )
` and `wireframe(z~x*y, data=grid, shade=TRUE, scales=list(arrows=FALSE))`

Comment: @TooTone Of course! I've edited the answer so that it corresponds directly to your posed question.

Comment: @TooTone May I ask you to accept my answer if you think that I've answered your question? Please tell me if you need me to add or change something! Thank you very much.

Comment: no worries I usually wait a bit before accepting answers as I accepted one too early once. Your answer is good; the only slight  query I have is whether the `outer` call assumes that the outer product ordering of (x,y) pairs is the same as that produced by `expand.grid`. Would `grid$z = with(grid, pmin(x,y))` be an alternative?

Comment: @TooTone I wasn't aware of `with` but it seems to be the better solution indeed (changed). Sorry, I didn't want to rush you.